# What is it for a module `super` be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to read some codes from rails. And i don't understand some of it. Hope getting some help.

The code from `active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb`. The method is `autoload`.

```
 def autoload(const_name, path = @_at_path)
  unless path
    full = [name, @_under_path, const_name.to_s].compact.join("::")
    path = Inflector.underscore(full)
  end

  if @_eager_autoload
    @_autoloads[const_name] = path
  end

  super const_name, path
end
```

- My question is what the `super` will be in here.
- Is there a doc or books tell about the sources？

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby super keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597643/ruby-super-keyword)

Comment: It's hard to say whether the asker is unaware what `super` does, or ze doesn't know what the superclass will be _in this particular case_.

Comment: BTW, i know the super method. I just want to know what the super will be in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method in question is defined as an instance method owned by the module `ActiveSupport::Autoload`. Since this is a module, in order for the instance method to ever become active, the module has to be included in some class. What `super` will be depends on what this class is. All ancestors of the class in question will be looked up in order for the `#autoload` method. If none of them defines it, `Kernel#autoload` will be hit, which is always there.

Comment: Thanks. I forget the `kernel#autoload` method.

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a ruby method that calls the same named method, in this case `autoload`, from the class it inherits from. I don't know if I made myself clear as english isn't my native language, so I'll show you through example:

```
class Human
  def shout(words)
    puts "I am yelling #{words}"
  end
end

class Person < Human
  def shout(words)
    puts "I am #{words}"
    puts super "loud"
  end
 end

Person.new.shout("awesome")

Output:
I am awesome
I am yelling loud
```