# How can i understand Ruby "super" in the context of super(options.merge(include: :comments))?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

In stacking AngularJS ontop of RoR, I'm seen examples of using something like below in model files,

```
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :comments))
  end
```

My understanding is that this allows the JSON post hash to include the comment hash inside of it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Fictional example**

```
posts : [
    {id: 0, name: 'friday night', comments: {
        {id: 0, body: "that was a great night"},
        {id: 1, body: "i agree"}
        }   
    }
]
```

**Definition of `super` from other SO post**

> super keyword invokes a method with the same name as the current
>   method in the superclass of the current class.
>   [ruby super keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597643/ruby-super-keyword)

... so what is `super` actually doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your model extends `ActiveRecord::Base`, right? For example,

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  # ... 
end
```

`ActiveRecord::Base` defines a `as_json` method. If you don't define `def as_json` in your model, you can still call `as_json` on an instance because it *inherits* that behavior from its superclass, `ActiveRecord::Base`.

---

Second, did you know that `ActiveRecord::Base#as_json` accepts some options? For example, using `only:` will restrict the JSON to the attributes you specify ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)).

Given that information, you could call `as_json` like this:

```
post.as_json(only: [:title, :published_at]) #=> {title: "...", published_at: "..."}
```

`include:` is one of the options which you can pass to `as_json`.

---

Third, `super` is used for calling the *same method in a superclass*. So, in this case:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def as_json(options = {})
    super 
  end 
end
```

`super` will call `ActiveRecord::Base#as_json`. That's good because that method defines this behavior!

Calling `super` with **no** arguments will simply pass the *original* arguments to that method call. So, these are equivalent:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  # `options` hash is passed _implicitly_:
  super 
end 

def as_json(options = {})
  # `options` hash is passed _explicitly_:
  super(options)
end
```

BUT, if you want, you can modify `options` before sending it to super. In your example, that's what is happening:

def as_json(options = {}) 
     # add `include: :comments` to any provided options
     new_options = options.merge(include: :comments)
     # pass the modified options to `super` 
     super(new_options)
   end

This way, you can be sure you're *always* passing `include: :comments` to `ActiveRecord::Base`'s implementation of `as_json`!

---

Hope that helps!